# Why can't I trust a Bluetooth device which is not available?

Tags: bluetooth

```
$ bluetoothctl trust 00:1E:B5:8F:38:1E
Device 00:1E:B5:8F:38:1E not available
```

I'm able to trust it, if it turns up in scans, but why can't I just add a trust without the device being available?

Comment: Doesn't trusting involve *exchanging* data with the device? There should be something on the other end for an exchange to complete. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27596841/2072269

Comment: That's about pairing. I guess "trust" as used here is a purely local thing, but it might require that the device is currently/has been previously paired. But bluetooth is mostly magic to me.